# HttpClient.PatchAsync throws PlatformNotSupportedException on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm having a weird behavior with the latest Visual Studio for MAC, and latest XCode 11.1 installed on my machine.
My project uses the HttpClient class provided by the System.Net.Http nuget package.

When being executed on an iOS simulator or an iPhone, the following code throws a PlatformNotSupportedException:

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  await client.PatchAsync("https://www.google.Fr", new StringContent(""));
```

With previous versions of both Visual Studio and XCode, it was working fine (the address does not really matter here, it is used as an example, only the fact of calling PatchAsync on an HttpClient matters).

I've been able to reproduce it in a brand new Xamarin.iOS project, but I struggle to find any documentation on why that might happen since the latest release of iOS and Xamarin. Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83521/pcl-httpmethod-patch-doesnt-exist

Comment: Interesting ... I'll try this workaround, but that does not really tell me, why the PatchAsync method worked in pre-XCode 11 versions ...

Comment: I checked the document and also did not find anything about change to `PatchAsync`. You can open a new issue on `Github` with a sample which can reproduce this problem. I'm updating my `XCode` and I will try it later.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Like I said in my post, it is pretty easy to reproduce. But you can find my sample project here => https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WEMbsvXm9oU48J1UnFvEHMox91FiJ1A9 

Execute it on an iOS 13.1 simulator, using VS for mac 8.3.4 (and XCode 11.1) and you should see the same behavior as me. Let me know if that's not the case !

Comment: Just so you know, I opened the following issue on Xamarin's github https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7236

Comment: Sure, I will try after the updating and let you know the result.

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same exception as you.